# C++ interface for hdiutil on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, hdiutil

Does a system call or library exist that would allow my C++ code to use hdiutil on Mac OS X. My code needs to mount an available .dmg file and then manipulate what's inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use Objective-C++, you can use NSTask to run command line tools:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/hdiutil"];
[task setArguments:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"attach", @"/path/to/dmg/file", nil]];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
if (0 != [task terminationStatus])
    NSLog(@"Mount failed.");
[task release];
```

If you need to use "plain" C++, you can use system():

```
if (0 != system("/usr/bin/hdiutil attach /path/to/dmg/file"))
    puts("Mount failed.");
```

or fork()/exec().

You'll need to double-check whether `hdiutil` actually returns 0 for success or not.

Answer (score 3):

`hdiutil` uses DiskImages.framework; unfortunately, the framework is private (undocumented, no headers), but if you're feeling adventurous, you can [try to use it anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186077/186122#186122).

Comment: Hi, I'm just doing some research in hdiutil private framworks in order to attach DMG file programmatically (file that represent disk image with since HFS+ partition). I wonder if you happen to dig a little inside DiskImages framework and look for the right method ? thanks

Comment: @Zohar81 you'll want class-dump for that: http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/

Answer (score 1):

`hdiutil` has a `-plist` argument that causes it to format its output as a standard OS X plist.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949879/get-the-path-of-the-dmg-from-the-mount-point/1949933) for info on processing the output from hdiutil; because you'll likely have to examine the output a bit to find what you need, it may be easy to do this initially with something like `python`.  Then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539396/apples-property-list-plist-implementation-in-c) for some suggestions on parsing plists in C++.